# Is there a command for "Show Invisibles" in Atom?

Tags: keymapping, atom-editor

Is there a command available to key mapping for toggling the display of invisibles in the Atom editor. A Show/Hide Invisibles command?

Where would I go to look for such a command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what worked for me using the Mac version:

```
'.editor':
   'ctrl-i': 'window:toggle-invisibles'
```

Comment: this works when I replaced '.editor' with 'body' in keymap.cson

Comment: Yep, this worked for me: `body:'ctrl-i': 'window:toggle-invisibles'` in `keymap.cson` as well (found in **Atom** > **Keymap...**)

Comment: hmm, this seems to work for me only other file types.  except for python (.py).  i checked the python language settings to ensure 'show Invisibles' is set, but that still doesn't help.

Answer (score 30):

**YES**

For Linux and Windows:
1) hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `keymap`
2) select `Application: open your keymap` and add the following 2 lines to that file:

```js
'body':
  'shift-ctrl-i': 'window:toggle-invisibles'
```

Or any non-conflicting keystroke combination of your liking instead of `shift-ctrl-i`.

---

**Note**
*For further detail, read [documentation on CSON fromat (season)](https://github.com/bevry/cson) and [atom-editor](/questions/tagged/atom-editor)'[s implementaton of cson](https://github.com/atom/season).*

Answer (score 17):

You can open the Command Palette (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and search for the `Window: Toggle Invisibles` command. Selecting that command should toggle invisibles on/off.

Answer (score 3):

For Atom 1.58.0 on Mac, open Settings, Keybindings, and click on the 'your keymap file' link above the search box. Add the following two lines to the bottom of the file and save it:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-i': 'window:toggle-invisibles'
```

Pressing Ctrl and i will then toggle on and off the invisible characters